# Android scoped storage access permissions not enforced?

Tags: android, android-permissions

Having difficulty understanding scoped storage and how it is used and enforced.
According to the android docs here -> https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#storage-permission

```
To access media files that other apps have created, you must declare the appropriate 
storage-related permissions, and the files must reside in one of the following media 
collections:

MediaStore.Images
MediaStore.Video
MediaStore.Audio
```

I have an app that expects to attach local files - images or PDFs - to an invoice.  Running on a device running Android 13, I would have expected, given the documentation, that my app would not be able to access an image created by a 3rd party app, but that's not the case.  The app can access any file, whether is downloads, a specific folder from a 3rd party app.  I haven't added any extra permissions but the app has no issues pulling images from a tiktok folder, or anywhere.

Maybe I don't understand the phrase "media files that other apps have created" - I would have thought a TIkTok video, or Lensa image or Toon-Art images in their respective folders would not be accessible from another app, but they are.

What am I missing here?

Comment: If your app requests READ_MEDIA_IMAGES permission it can read all image files of other apps. This permission is not needed for image files created by the app itself. All has nothing to do with scoped storage.

Comment: We don't have that permission set either.